# Unexpected data sorting result after filtering from parent and child node

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have list of tree node `metadataList` Like below:

```
   [
  {
    "data": {
      "metadata": {
        "category": [
          "Csp"
        ]
      }
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "data": {
          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Csp"
            ]
          }
        },
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Mpn"
            ]
          }
        },
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Mpn"
            ]
          }
        },
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Mpn"
            ]
          }
        },
        "children": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "metadata": {
        "category": [
          "Isv"
        ]
      }
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "data": {
          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Isv"
            ]
          }
        },
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Isv"
            ]
          }
        },
        "children": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "metadata": {
        "category": [
          "Csp"
        ]
      }
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "data": {
          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Csp"
            ]
          }
        },
        "children": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "metadata": {
        "category": [
          "Mpn"
        ]
      }
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "data": {
          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Mpn"
            ]
          }
        },
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Mpn"
            ]
          }
        },
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Mpn"
            ]
          }
        },
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Csp"
            ]
          }
        },
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Isv"
            ]
          }
        },
        "children": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "metadata": {
        "category": [
          "Incentives"
        ]
      }
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "data": {
          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Incentives"
            ]
          }
        },
        "children": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Which is a type of array of `data` and `children` collection it's class like below:

```
export default class CurrentTopicMetadataTreeNode {
    public data: CurrentTopicMetadata;
    public children: CurrentTopicMetadataTreeNode[];
}

export default class CurrentTopicMetadata {
    public id: string;
    public metadata: TopicMetadata 

}

export class TopicMetadata {
    public category: Category[] 

}

export enum Category {
    Csp = 'Csp',
    Mpn = 'Mpn',
    Incentives = 'Incentives',
    Referrals = 'Referrals',
    Isv = 'Isv',

}
```

What I am trying,  to filter list as `data` and `children` order as per category. Let say if filter by a category all data and children belongs to that category should come like below order.

[image]

But I am getting data like this order :

[image]

**`One Element On Array Problem Set:`**

Here in this array if I search with `Csp` Only data in root node which is `Csp` and data in `children` only has one `data` which contains `Csp` would be in array.

```
[{
    "data": {
      "metadata": {
        "category": [
          "Csp"
        ]

      }


    },
    "children": [
      {
        "data": {

          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Csp"
            ]

          }



        },
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "data": {

          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Mpn"
            ]
          }



        },
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "data": {

          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Mpn"
            ]
          }

        },
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "data": {

          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Mpn"
            ]

          }

        },
        "children": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
```

**`Expected Output:`** So after filtered by `Csp` node should be look like this:

```
[
  {
    "data": {
      "metadata": {
        "category": [
          "Csp"
        ]
      }
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "data": {
          "metadata": {
            "category": [
              "Csp"
            ]
          }
        },
        "children": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

here is my code, where I am doing wrong?

```js
// Rule 1 check parent metadata category whether be empty

// Rule 2 and 3
function find_in_children(children, parent_category) {
    children_has_same_category = []
    for(var i in children) {
        let child = children[i];
        if(child.children != undefined && child.children.length > 0 && child.data.metadata.category == parent_category) {
            children_has_same_category.push(child);
        }
    }
    if(children_has_same_category.length > 0) {
        return children_has_same_category
    } else {
        for(var i in children) {
            let child = children[i];
            return find_in_children(child.children, parent_category);
        }
    }
}

function check_object(object) {
    let parent_category = object.data.metadata.category[0];
    if(object.children != undefined && object.children.length > 0) {
        return {'data': object.data, 'children': find_in_children(object.children, parent_category)}
    } else {
        return {'data': object.data}
    }
}

function apply_rules(object) {
    // Rule 1 check parent metadata category whether be empty
    if(object.data.metadata.category.length > 0) {
        return {'data': object.data}
    } else {
        return check_object(object)
    }
}

 target = {
    value: 'Isv'
}
filtered_datas = []
for(var i in datas) {
    let data = datas[i];
    if(data.data.metadata.category.length > 0) {
        result = apply_rules(data)
        if(result.data.metadata.category[0] == target.value) {
            filtered_datas.push(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the data sample and result: https://jsfiddle.net/faridkiron/b02cksL8/#&togetherjs=F7FK3fBULx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve above problem like below way:

```
const findMatchedChild = (nodeInList, type) => {
    const node = Object.assign({}, nodeInList) 
    node.children = nodeInList.children
        .filter(child => child.data.metadata.category.includes(type))
        .map(child => findMatchedChild(child, type))
    return node
}


const cspList = findMatchedChild({ children: data }, 'Csp').children
console.log(JSON.stringify(cspList, null, 2));
```

Got the expected result.